# Superimpose a line on a surface in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to superimpose a line on a surface, but I have a minor problem. There are some  view points in which the line isn't visible. For example, try plotting the surface that is generated by the code below:

```
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D
import pylab as p
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker 
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource

vima=0.2

def fun(x, y):
  return x**3 + y

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = np.arange(0.1, 50, vima)
Y = np.arange(0.1, 10.2, vima)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

Z=fun(X,Y)

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,rstride=25, cstride=75, alpha=1, color='0.8',  linewidth=0.2, shade=True)

Y=(10.0-0.2*X)/0.9798
Z=Z*0
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
ax.grid(on=True)
ax.view_init(elev=34,azim=-106)

Z=fun(X,Y)
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)#, linewidth=1)

ax.w_xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.NullLocator()) 
ax.w_yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.NullLocator()) 
ax.w_zaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.NullLocator()) 


ax.set_xlabel('$x$')

ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
ax.set_zlabel('$z$')


fig.suptitle('b', fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

I assume that initialy you can see the surface, a line on xy plane and a line superimposed on the surface. But if you rotate this plot you will find that there are some view points that the superimposed line isn't visible.

Is there a way to overcome this little bug?

Thank you in advance

Comment: to my knowledge this is a limitation of 3d plotting in matplotlib. As an alternative, you may try using [mayavi](http://mayavi.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I am very satisfied by matplotlib's plot quality, that's why I would like to find a solution on this problem. I'll give a try to mayavi anyway.